# running operation in background thread and have a completion block?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a task which is reading from a disk, potentially going to take quite some time, so don't want to do it in a main thread.. and what I want is to call a function X after reading from the disk. What is the best way to do this in iOS?

So far this is what I've tried:

```
 NSInvocationOperation *processDataOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(readDisk:) object:nil];
                [processDataOperation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryHigh];
                [processDataOperation setCompletionBlock:^(void){
                     NSMutableArray *feedItemsArray = [self generateFeedItemsFromDictionary:streamDiskData];
                     [self postFetchCompletedNotificationForDict:queryStringDict withFeedItems:feedItemsArray isFresh:NO];
                }];
```

basically I am using NSInvocationOperation and then set it's completion block, however the issue is that in my completion block I need the result that is generated in readDisk. How do I access that in the completion block? It's nearly imposible right?

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using NSInvocations it is possible, but far more complicated than necessary, to achieve a trivial amount of work beyond the main thread.

Both GCD and NSOperations can be used to implement a wide array of concurrency strategies. From an object-oriented perspective, NSOperations are more highly abstracted than CGD blocks, which makes them (imo) easier to "design" with, and potentially optimized beyond the scope of where I'm implementing them. GCD is lower-level: This makes interacting with it appear slightly more complicated (it really isn't), but people who are in to that sorta stuff will tell you that it is "more efficient" and carries "less overhead".

My personal approach is to use NSOperations in scenarios where I have a designed/orchestrated concurrency pattern in my application, and use GCD for trivial concurrent/background operations.

If all I need to do is fire some arbitrary task that is not relevant to the design but needs to be done in the background, I'd use CGD. That's what I'd probably use in this case:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    [self readDisk];
    NSMutableArray *feedItemsArray = [weakSelf generateFeedItemsFromDictionary:streamDiskData];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //Call back to the main thread before performing/posting anything touching UIKit
        [self postFetchCompletedNotificationForDict:queryStringDict withFeedItems:feedItemsArray isFresh:NO];
        })
})];
```

Comment: may I know why you created __unsafe __unretained weakSelf = self;
 and not use self directly inside the blokc?

Comment: Sure - the block will will 'copy' the objects it references, which asserts ownership. This would mean that self owns the block, but the the block also owns self: That's the  makings of a retain loop. By explicitly referencing self weakly in the block, we avoid this possibility.

Comment: so the best practice is to use a weak reference when using self in blocks?

Comment: Using this code, I get an error pointing to the argument `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`:"Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'dispatch_queue_t' (aka 'NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue> *') is disallowed with ARC"

Comment: @NicolasMiari See improved answer, dispatch call was missing the correct code to access the background queue.

Comment: @isaac Yes, I found out too by looking up the headers/docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could always use grand central dispatch to do your operation in the background instead.

Since it is a block you can just call the method normally and store the result. Then grab the main queue if you need to update any UI or do whatever you need to after completion.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("read disc", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    result = [self readDisc];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //update UI or do whatever you need to do with the result of readDisc
    });
});
dispatch_release(queue);
```

Comment: I think everyone almost agrees that NSOperation are more preferable than GCD?

Comment: I think that which one you use is really situational. Grand Central Dispatch is good when you only want to set up a block to execute at that one point in the code. While NSOperation has some more functionality and you can subclass and run it at different parts of your code. GCD just makes it easier in your situation to easily get the results of your background operation and use it in the main queue.

Comment: I also think that GCD is better when using iOS as NSOperation does no utilise GCD like it does when programming for mac. The down side of this is you can end up with lots of threads meaning that the os has to keep switching. GCD will optimise and add a block to a existing queue which has the same priority e.t.c this can save process power and time.